# Не работает SetActive()

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не удается в принципе реализовать SetActive() для окна InputField, в VS он подчеркивается красной линией, а при сохранении скрипта не удается запустить игру. В других скриптах не фигурирует, game object назначен в инспекторе. С чем это может быть связано?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public InputField AnswerField;

void Start()
{
   AnswerField.SetActive(false);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D co)
{
   if (co.tag=="name")
   {
      AnswerField.SetActive(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: а какую ошибку пишет VS или консоль Unity?

Comment: VS выдает CS1061

Comment: Полный текст ошибки а не цифру....аналогично с Unity

Comment: файл выглядит ровно так, как представлен в вопросе? Или объявление класса намеренно тут не указано?

Comment: InputField не содержит определения SetActive, и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения SetActive, принимающий тип InputField в качестве первого аргумента

Comment: public class PacmanMovie : MonoBehaviour

Comment: Вот, отлично. вам русским языком пишут что не так.... и даже в документацию если посмотреть https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html   Где там метод SetActive?

Comment: ActivateInputField тоже пробовала, не работает. Окно сразу появляется, хотя сначала должно быть неактивно

Answer (score 1):

[SetActive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) это метод [GameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html).

```
gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

`InputField` это [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html), а не [GameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html).

`MonoBehaviour` это **КОМПОНЕНТ** для `GameObject`.

*Не путать тёплое с мягким !!!*

У компонентов есть ссылка на `GameObject`, к которому они принадлежат.

```
AnswerField.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

SetActive - метод GameObject-a.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public GameObject AnswerField;

void Start()
{
   AnswerField.SetActive(false);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D co)
{
   if (co.tag=="name")
   {
      AnswerField.SetActive(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: но ActivateInputField тоже не работает

Comment: `SetActive` - для GameObject, `ActivateInputField` - для InputField.

Comment: @Алёна что значит тоже? Код который я кинул точно работает.